# Check if std::stringstream contains a character - buffering until \n

Tags: android, c++, stringstream

Because I was unable to find how to output raw data in android debug output (eg. without `\n` automatically inserted), I decided to subclass our logging library and buffer the input until `\n` appears.

Our logging library accepts huge number of data formats, so I decided to create a template method:

```
template<typename T>
bool addToLog(std::stringstream* stream, android_LogPriority priority, T data) {
    // Add new data to sstream
    stream<<data;
    //If the stream now contains new line
    if(stream->PSEUDO_containsCharacter('\n')) {
        // remove everything before '\n' from stream and add it to string
        std::string str = stream->PSEUDO_getAllStringBefore('\n');
        // Log the line
        __android_log_print(priority, "", "%s", str.c_str());
        // Remove \n from stream
        stream->PSEUDO_removeFirstCharacter();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I don't know how to check whether the `\n` is in the stream and remove everything before it. Which is what I need - buffer data until `\n`, then send the data (without `\n`) to android logging library.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `std::getline`?

Comment: @LogicStuff I thought that only works on standard input, I've never seen it being used for purpose like this one.

Comment: `std::stringstream` and `std::fstream` are both standard streams - [see the hierarchy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io).

Comment: @LogicStuff yeah, I already looked it up of course. But that's now, which is long after I posted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On way to you can check if the stream contains a newline in it is to use [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) on the underlying string of the stringstream.  If the stream contains a newline then we can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to extract the part of the buffer before the newline and output it to the log.

```
template<typename T>
bool addToLog(std::stringstream& stream, android_LogPriority priority, T data) {
    // Add new data to sstream
    stream << data;
    //If the stream now contains new line
    if(stream.str().find_first_of('\n', 0) != std::string::npos) {
        // remove everything before '\n' from stream and add it to string
        std::string str;
        std::getline(stream, str);  //gets output until newline and discards the newline
        // Log the line
        __android_log_print(priority, "", "%s", str.c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: @LogicStuff Thanks for noticing that.  That is what the OP had and I just copied it.  I changed it to a reference as there is no reason I can see to pass it by pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver The reason I use pointer is that there's separate stream for every loglevel, and those are in constant-size array. So I just pass the array pointer (with an offset) - derefferencing just to make a refference (ain't this terminology confusing?) would not really improve performance.

Comment: Also you did not understand the question properly. I receive number of `T`s which added to stream. And I want to print the stream **iff** the string contains new line. You print it every time. That breaks the purpose of using the stream at all.

Comment: @TomášZato Well that wasn;t very clear in your question.  If you only want to print `data` if there is a newline in it then you just have to check if there is anything left in the stream after the call to `getline`.  I have updated my answer to show that

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to ask - what's unclear in *"buffer the input **until** `\n` appears"*? Buffering implies multiple chunks of input. You know I am really trying, but I can't see how to say that so that it's clear for the reader.

Comment: @TomášZato I am sorry.  I was having a total brain fart.  I have updated the answer.  Let me know if that does what you want.