# Stringstream. Detect end of line

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

Is there way to detect end of line in stringstream? 
My file:

```
1/2
2/3
3/4
4/5
```

Something like that is not working:

```
stringstream buffer;
buffer << file.rdbuf();
string str;
getline(buffer, str);
...
istringstream ss(str);
int num;
ss >> num;      
if (ss.peek() == '/') //WORKS AS EXPECTED!
{...}
if(ss.peek() == '\n') //NOT WORKING! SKIPS THIS CONDITION.
{...}
```

This is was warned:

```
if(ss.telg() == -1) //WARNED!
             ~~~~~
{...}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: maybe you're on Windows? if so, the "end line" is 2 characters: \r\n

Comment: How are you loading `str`? `string str;
istringstream ss(str);` can't be the whole story. If it's with `std::getline`, `getline` politely removes the EOL for you.

Comment: Yes it's with getline(stringstream, str). Thanks. Answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::istringstream` has an [`eof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) method:

> Returns true if the associated stream has reached end-of-file. Specifically, returns true if `eofbit` is set in `rdstate()`.

```
string str;
istringstream ss(str);
int num;
ss >> num;
if (ss.eof()) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `find_first_of`:

```
std::string str_contents = buffer.str();
if(str_contents.find_first_of('\n') != std::string::npos) {
   //contains EOL
}
```

`find_first_of('\n')` returns the first instance of the EOL character. If there are none, then it returns (a very large index) `std::string::npos`. If you know that there is a EOL character in your string, you can get the the first line using

```
std::string str;
std::getline(buffer, str);
```

Also see [NathanOliver's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068094/check-if-stdstringstream-contains-a-character-buffering-until-n)